# CSS spinner not working for IE working as expected in Chrome

Tags: css, frontend

CSS spinner not working for IE working as expected in Chrome  below is the code for animation I have added in my CSS

```
div.myLoader .spinner > div {
    background-color: #333;
    height: 100%;
    width: 6px;
    display: inline-block;

    -webkit-animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}
```

code for animation:

```
@keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
    0%, 40%, 100% {
        transform: scaleY(0.4);
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4);
    }
    20% {
        transform: scaleY(1.0);
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0);
    }
}
```

please help me to get solution.

Comment: What is it not doing? Which version of IE? What is your HTML structure? Could you be more specific?

Comment: @keyframes are supported from ie10 , ie9 doesn'support this [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=keyframes)

Comment: IE9 and above, I am using react js and CSS. Loader spinner is not working. it is coming as white dot